# Ubuntu 22 Firefox fails to start with symbollically linked home directory

Tags: firefox, snap, home-directory, 22.04, symbolic-link

On installing Ubuntu 22 in a separate new partition on a machine previously running Ubuntu 20, I have replaced the installed /home/chris with a symbolic link to my old /home/chris directory in another partition.
Firefox then will not start and tells me that /home/chris/snap is not a directory even though it is there and is a directory.
If I switch back to the /home/chris installed with Ubuntu 22 it works fine!
Is there a way of getting it to work with the symbolically linked home directory?
With this home directory in place, removing and purging firefox with snap and then reinstalling does not help!